# JSF preload list for datatable in page

Tags: jsf, ejb-3.0

I'm using EJB and JSF. I made a jsp simple page with a button "get list". When it's clicked, a managed bean method is called that sets the list, which is then displayed in the jsp with the dataTable tag.

The question is, how can I pre load this list/dataTable on page load without having to click the button?

This is the method that's called through the button action on the jsp:

```
public String retrieveList() {
    items = facade.getAllItem();
    return "";
}
```

this is the part of the jsp:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{mybean.items}" var="sup"
    binding="#{mybean.dataTable}"
    rowClasses="oddRow, evenRow"
    styleClass="tableStyle"
    headerClass="tableHeader"
    columnClasses="column1, column2, column1, column1, column1, column1">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotate the method with [`@PostConstruct`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) and get rid of return value.

```
@PostConstruct
public void retrieveList() {
    items = facade.getAllItem();
}
```

This way the method will be executed immediately *after* construction of the bean and injection of all `@EJB` dependencies. In the JSF page you just have to bind to `#{bean.items}` the usual way.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark the most helpful answer to accepted. See also http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a method init with @postConstruct

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
  items = facade.getAllItem();
}
```

This will return the items only on bean creation ,